# Multiple EnvironmentFile(s) for systemd service file

Tags: systemd, environment-variables

I'm using Celery alongside Django, and because I'm running into [This Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076295/gunicorn-environment-variable-setting/) (Gunicorn not having access to OS environment variables) I've had to set `EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment` within my `gunicorn.service` file to access things like `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` etc.

This works perfectly, no issues.

However when trying to get Celery setup, it's running into the same problem.  My struggle is that celery already makes use of `EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery` and I'd sort of like to keep my gunicorn and celery environment files separate...

I tried `EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment /etc/conf.d/celery` but of course this "Failed to load environment files"

Is it possible to load multiple environment files?
Or have one environment file "call" another"?
Or to simply load all environment files in a particular directory?

Comment: The [systemd.exec specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) says *"This option may be specified more than once in which case all specified files are read."* so have you tried breaking it into separate lines like `EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment` and `EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery` ?

Comment: woohoo that worked!  oddly enough that exact same url timed out for me earlier when I tried to visit the page...  do you want to put this into an answer?

Comment: Why don't you add an answer - since you actually tried it ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

looks like according to https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=

`EnvironmentFile=` *...may be specified more than once in which case all specified files are read.*

So all I needed was

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery
```

Thanks to @steeldriver for the help!